Is converting output values from reduced units to physical units a good idea?
I have written a program for MC simulation of LJ particles in NVT.
I have used reduced units to run simulations.
My professor wants me to show him data and plot it in physical units.
Is converting values from reduced units to physical units enough, or do I need to rewrite my program and run all the simulations again?

You will find that it is impossible to get the program to even compute in physical units. You are always meant to compute in reduced units and then convert the results to physical units.

An accepted answer to this question can be found here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/13821/5
